# How can I get a facebook user first_name from app scoped user id

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I don't convert user app_scoped_user_id to user_id.

But, i'd like user **first_name**.

If I sent http://graph.facebook.com/{user_id}  then I get the correct informations (like: http://graph.facebook.com/100005247134894 ) but

If I sent http://graph.facebook.com/{app_scoped_user_id} then I get error (like: http://graph.facebook.com/265257860325783 )

How I can get **first_name** with app_scoped_user_id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have a user with access token ABCDE trying to access the first name of another user who has app-scoped user ID of 314159:

`https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=314159&fields=first_name&access_token=ABCDE`

But if you don't have an access token, then getting first name is [no longer possible](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading).

`In v1.0, there were API endpoints that didn't require an access token to call. In v2.0, all calls to endpoints now require an access token, except for calls to get an object's picture.`

Answer (score 1):

You should always use `/me` if you're using an User Access Token to request the User's information. With that, you can avoid the hassle with the different user_ids.

Furthermore, if you use the app-scoped user_ids, you also need to make the requests either with an App Access Token of the same App you acquired the app-scoped user_id with, or with the respective User Access Token.

Comment: I have several app_scoped_user_id... not mine only. And I want to show this users first_name

Comment: As I wrote, this will only work with the respective app. You need to understand that `/me` is always relative to the user encoded in the Access Token!